# Русская документация Java

Tags: java, документация

Где можно найти грубо говоря русскую документацию Java? Если её нет. Или ресурсы хорошие на Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте книги: Философия Java и Эффективная Java. Своего рода документация на русском и хорошо поймете работу Java языка.
А русские ресурсы хорошие:
http://study-java.ru/
и http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru

Comment: Cпасибо большое вам!

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, то примите его, нажав галочку рядом с ним.